# How to reject repetition of character within Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for help with a Java regular expression please.

My regular expression should accept a string of length 5 only, with characters matching [BDILMOP] only.

No repeated characters are allowed - eg. BDILM is allowed, but BDILL or BDLLL are not.

Please help - I'm new to regex and so would appreciate any advice that you could throw my way.

Thanks!

Comment: Consecutive repeated characters, or repeated anywhere? e.g. is "IBIBI" allowed?

Comment: They're not allowed to be repeated anywhere within the expression - ie only one character out of [BDILMOP] is allowed to exist in the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[BDILMOP]{5}$
```

`(?!.*(.).*\1)` is negative lookahead which fails the match if there is any repetition in input. `(.)` captures a letter in group #1 and `\1` is back-reference of the same group thus checking repetition.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW9jB1/3)

Comment: Thank you - could you please explain why the last character of a matching string appears to be highlighted?

Comment: This works fine in the demo - however when I use a builder pattern to pass my test string in to a util method that calls "matches" on the regex, I'm getting failures for repeated characters. Not sure why!

Comment: I've sorted it now, thanks - as a side note, how could I check for character duplication in any given string, not just a string containing the subset of characters mentioned above?

Comment: That would be this regex: `^(?!.*(.).*\1).+$`